# How do I query for data in Rhythmbox

Tags: python, gio, rhythmbox

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and I'm trying to write a python plugin to query the Rhythmbox database.  The Rhythmbox version is v2.96 but this issue also occurs with v2.97 as well.  When I do a python query, Ubuntu crashes with a segmentation fault.

I need to confirm the following is correct and if I've found a bug specific to Ubuntu or if I've misunderstood how to correctly query.  If anyone else using another distro can confirm - this would be most welcome.

I've filed a [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=682294) on bugzilla with regards to the segmentation fault.  However, my question is not strictly about this - its specifically trying to confirm the correct python code to query for data.

Thus my question:  is the code snippet below correct to query the Rhythmbox database or do I need to install an additional package to enable querying.

Steps:

1. Enable the python console plugin
2. type (or copy and paste line by line the following)

```
from gi.repository import RB, GLib

db = shell.props.db
query_model = RB.RhythmDBQueryModel.new_empty(db)
query = GLib.PtrArray()

db.query_append_params( query, RB.RhythmDBQueryType.EQUALS, RB.RhythmDBPropType.ARTIST, 'some artist name' )
db.query_append_params( query, RB.RhythmDBQueryType.EQUALS, RB.RhythmDBPropType.TITLE, 'some song name' )   

db.do_full_query_parsed(query_model, query)

for row in query_model:
    print row[0].get_string( RB.RhythmDBPropType.ARTIST )
    print row[0].get_string( RB.RhythmDBPropType.TITLE )
```

If ubuntu 12.04 when I type this line, Ubuntu crashes with a segmentation fault

```
db.query_append_params( query, RB.RhythmDBQueryType.EQUALS, RB.RhythmDBPropType.ARTIST, 'some artist name' )
```

Thus, have I actually used the first parameter in the call correctly - the Query Pointer Array (PtrArray) - or is my query function parameters incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### and the answer is...

Well, this issue is indeed a bug - but to answer my own question,

**yes** the syntax to query for data in Rhythmbox is as correctly stated in the question.

*and there is a however...*

Querying for data only works for 64bit linux.

Yes really - I have been testing 32bit live-cd's of Fedora 17 as well as LMDE.  Both exhibit the same segmentation fault issue as Ubuntu 12.04.

The common factor is that I was testing Ubuntu 12.04/Fedora 17 and LMDE in their 32bit incarnations.

Testing all three in their 64bit variants works as expected.

The 32bit issue is a bug - and has been reported on bugzilla - but the question as posed has been answered.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this too. I managed to work around it by iterating through the library manually:

```
    for row in self.shell.props.library_source.props.base_query_model:
        entry = row[0]
        artist = entry.get_string(RB.RhythmDBPropType.ARTIST)
        if self.sanitize(artist) in similar_artists_map:
            self.qm.add_entry(entry, -1)
```