# Rhythmbox plugin. Get one number limited of songs

Tags: python-3.x, plugins, rhythmbox

Get all songs:

```
for row in self.shell.props.library_source.props.base_query_model:
    print(row[0].get_string(RB.RhythmDBPropType.TITLE))
```

I need get only 10 songs (for example).

**First try:**

```
self.shell.props.library_source.props.base_query_model.set_property("limit-value", GLib.Variant("n", 10))
for row in self.shell.props.library_source.props.base_query_model:
    print(row[0].get_string(RB.RhythmDBPropType.TITLE))
```

**Result:**

```
Warning: g_object_set_property: construct property "limit-value" for object 'RhythmDBQueryModel' can't be set after construction
  self.shell.props.library_source.props.base_query_model.set_property("limit-value", GLib.Variant("n", 10))
```

**Second try:** I do not know how to set the limit value because try with GENRE

```
db = self.shell.props.db
query_model = RB.RhythmDBQueryModel.new_empty(db)
query = GLib.PtrArray()
db.query_append_params(query, RB.RhythmDBQueryType.EQUALS, RB.RhythmDBPropType.GENRE, "Salsa")

db.do_full_query_parsed(query_model, query)

for row in query_model:
    print(row[0].get_string(RB.RhythmDBPropType.ARTIST))
```

**Result:**
Rhythmbox closed. Error detailed in:  [How do I query for data in Rhythmbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133250/how-do-i-query-for-data-in-rhythmbox?rq=1)

Comment: slicing the first query is not an option ? (`for row in self.shell.props.library_source.props.base_query_model[0:10]`)

Comment: Thanks for you comment, but not working.    TypeError: 'slice' object is not iterable

Comment: According to this [doc](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/RB-3.0/classes/Source.html#properties) `base_query_model` is read-only indeed, can you manage something with `query_model` ? otherwise a dirty index to break the loop...

Comment: @PRMoureu I update my question with second try. About your suggestion, I want get only 10 songs before the iteration, similar to: SELECT name FROM table LIMIT 10